# how to return several variables from a php script to a div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php script that runs a select query and stores values in variables. i want to display these values in a div using jquery. (I am using the jquery post method to run the php script)

thanks!

my php code is:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$post_val=$_REQUEST["l_val"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question_master where master_q_no=".($post_val);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    $row=$result->fetch_row();
    $output=json_encode($row);
     echo $output;
}
$conn->close();
```

### ?>

this code is called from another file and the jquery code which calls this file is:

```
$.post("post_text_updated.php",{ l_val:$("#lastvalue").text(),       s_cat:cat_elem.value},function(ajaxresult){
        $("#display_question").html(ajaxresult);
```

---

my question is: how/where do i access the php variable 'output'?

thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have attached my code.

Answer (score 0):

using `json_encode()` you can pass multiple variable. Then you can use jsonParse for retrieving it.

Comment: you need to store your variable in an array & then encode it in json format using that function.